# Сделать числа отрицательными

Tags: python

Есть код, который реверсирует ВСЕ числа.

```
def make_negative(number):
    result = [x * -1 for x in number] 
    return result
```

Как сделать так, чтобы только положительные числа подверглись реверсии?

Comment: `-abs(x)` (ну или как там в питоне получить абсолютное значение)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

```
def f1(lst):
    return list(map(lambda x: -abs(x), lst))

def f2(lst):
    return [-abs(x) for x in lst]
```

По сути они ничем не отличаются. Также, если вам не нужен будет доступ по индексу `lst[5]`, к примеру, а вы будете использовать их в цикле `for`, то можно возвращать не списки, а генератор (или объект `map`), т.к. они занимают меньше памяти

```
def f1(lst):
    return map(lambda x: -abs(x), lst)

def f2(lst):
    return (-abs(x) for x in lst)
```

Answer (score 4):

Есть такая функция  abs(). В вашем случае:

```
def make_negative(number):
    result = [abs(x) * -1 for x in number] 
    return result

print(make_negative([1,2,4,-12,-2]))
    [-1, -2, -4, -12, -2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Всё же если следовать заданию буквально, и никак не преобразовывать исходные числа, не подходящие под условие, то можно использовать *тернарный оператор*:

```py
result = [-x if x > 0 else x for x in number]
```

Answer (score 0):

А если надо отбросить отрицательные и вывести только реверс положительных, то

```
def make_negative(number):
    result = [x * -1 for x in number if x > 0] 
    return result

print(make_negative([1,2,4,-12,-2]))
[-1, -2, -4]
```

Answer (score 0):

В копилку

```py
result = [x * (-(x > 0) or 1) for x in range(-5, 6)]
# [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5]
```